# Cannot read property 'setState' of null - React.js, Modal, Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying React.js for the first time in trying to build this web app.  I am getting `Cannot read property 'setState' of null` on the specified line below.  I've been trying to figure out why for the past few hours and cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MyModal.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Button, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class MyModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
    }

    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Launch demo modal
          </Button>

          <Modal
            {...this.props}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={this.hideModal}
            dialogClassName="custom-modal"
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <h4>Wrapped Text</h4>
              <p>Blah</p>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>  // Chrome inspector says it errors on this line
          </Modal>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        );
    } // end render function

} // end export default
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

bind your component class methods inside the `constructor()` (binding inside constructor is better than binding inside `render()` for performance sake):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: false};
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I also posted a solution but I liked yours better so I will delete mine.

Comment: we don't want `.bind` to create a new function on every render :)

Comment: This totally fixed my problem but a reasonable question is why this boilerplate is necessary in the first place, and why there is no way to automate this with less code written by hand, instead, I would love to have this done for me so I cannot screw it up and leave it out. A real disappointment. Possible answer: is it because *constructor()* is in the "static" class of my component and not an instance method. Crappy "punish the programmer" API design.

Comment: ty Jared. React has some serious design flaws, not to mention the extreme complexity and learning curve. my friends are finding angular2 to rock

Comment: this isn't actually a React specific issue. This is how JavaScript works. If you write your classes in es5 (using `React.createClass`) class methods are automatically bound to the class. React doesn't induce too much learning curve compared to other frameworks as it only represents View in our MVC apps.