# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following react page and am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
```

when using the counter.
It seems to have to do with the `this` used by setState

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>counter</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-beta.3/react-router.min.js"></script>

<head>


<body>


    <div id="entry"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var destination = document.querySelector("#entry");



class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { value: 0};
    }

  increment(){
    this.setState(function(prevState){
      value: prevState.value + 1
    });
  };

  decrement(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Counter/>
    </div>,
    destination
)

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I just changed `increment` to an old style function and that didn't work.

Comment: Suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'setState' of null - React.js, Modal, Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694468/cannot-read-property-setstate-of-null-react-js-modal-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to pass the context around to your custom functions in ES6 mode of writing.

There are many ways to do it, a good starting point is this [sitepoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/) here.

As a start,change your constructor as -

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { value: 0};
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);

    }
```

You can do the same in `onClick` as well, but IMHO this seems neater